# Peoplesoft App Engine SQL using "WITH" clause

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, peoplesoft

My app engine keeps returning 'fatal sql error' when I'm trying to use a sql "WITH" clause.  Any other suggestions?

Here is my sql that works in sql dev, but no luck in App Engine...

```
WITH bj AS ( 
 SELECT FSU.EMPLID 
 ,FSU.EMPL_RCD 
 ,FSU.PLAN_TYPE 
 ,FSU.EFFDT 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT 
 ,FSU.ANNUAL_PLEDGE 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT || LEAD(FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT) OVER (PARTITION BY FSU.EMPLID 
 , FSU.PLAN_TYPE 
  ORDER BY FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT DESC 
  , FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT DESC) AS CODE 
  FROM PS_FSA_BENEFIT FSU 
 WHERE FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT <= '29-NOV-13' 
   AND FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT BETWEEN '01-JAN-13' AND '31-DEC-13' 
  ORDER BY FSU.EMPLID, FSU.PLAN_TYPE, FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT DESC, FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT DESC ) 
 SELECT * 
  FROM bj 
 WHERE bj.CODE IN ('TE', 'WE', 'EE', 'ET', 'EW', 'E') 
   AND bj.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT BETWEEN '16-NOV-13' AND '29-NOV-13' 
   AND bj.EFFDT = ( 
 SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) 
  FROM bj A_ED 
 WHERE bj.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
   AND bj.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD 
   AND bj.PLAN_TYPE = A_ED.PLAN_TYPE 
   AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
  ORDER BY bj.code, bj.emplid
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue in 8.48, but it seems recent peopletools release handle it. Whatever your version is, the following code should make the trick :

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM ( 
 SELECT FSU.EMPLID 
 ,FSU.EMPL_RCD 
 ,FSU.PLAN_TYPE 
 ,FSU.EFFDT 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT 
 ,FSU.ANNUAL_PLEDGE 
 ,FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT || LEAD(FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT) OVER (PARTITION BY FSU.EMPLID 
 , FSU.PLAN_TYPE 
  ORDER BY FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT DESC 
  , FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT DESC) AS CODE 
  FROM PS_FSA_BENEFIT FSU 
 WHERE FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT <= '29-NOV-13' 
   AND FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT BETWEEN '01-JAN-13' AND '31-DEC-13' 
  ORDER BY FSU.EMPLID, FSU.PLAN_TYPE, FSU.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT DESC, FSU.COVERAGE_BEGIN_DT DESC ) bj 
 WHERE bj.CODE IN ('TE', 'WE', 'EE', 'ET', 'EW', 'E') 
   AND bj.COVERAGE_ELECT_DT BETWEEN '16-NOV-13' AND '29-NOV-13' 
   AND bj.EFFDT = ( 
 SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) 
  FROM bj A_ED 
 WHERE bj.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
   AND bj.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD 
   AND bj.PLAN_TYPE = A_ED.PLAN_TYPE 
   AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
  ORDER BY bj.code, bj.emplid
```

Comment: I'm in 8.49.  Now it is giving me the "table or view does not exist" error... any other suggestions?